# Error Espacio(s) en blanco esperado(s) antes de delimitador. (near "" at position 272) al crear trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

estoy tratando de crear un trigger en mysql que luego de que se haga un insert en la tabla "det_asignacion_materials" , me reduzca la cantidad en la tabla: "det_ingreso_materials"

El codigo que estoy tratado de usar para el trigger es este:

```
   DELIMITER;;
CREATE TRIGGER reducirCantidad
AFTER INSERT det_asignacion_materials
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
UPDATE det_ingreso_materials SET cantidad = cantidad - NEW.cantidad
WHERE det_ingreso_materials.material_id = NEW.material_id
END
DELIMITER;;
```

No se si hay algun en la sintaxis, en el ejemplo que estoy siguiendo veo que funciona bien.

Saludos a todos

Comment: En lugar de usar delimitadores así // úsalos como ;; Es decir, DELIMITER ;; y ;; DELIMITER;

Comment: tampoco, me dice error en linea 1 DELIMITER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu trigger no tiene la sintaxis adecuada desde el momento en el que carece de:

- `ON tablaX`

Es decir indicar sobre que tabla se ejecutaría

- Además tu sentencia SQL de `update` debe finalizar con `;`
- Finalmente tampoco es necesario que para indicar el término del trigger vuelvas a declarar `DELIMITER ;;` con solo colocar la simbología de cierre alcanza

Luego de esos puntos ya debería funcionar:

```
DELIMITER;;
    CREATE TRIGGER reducirCantidad AFTER INSERT ON det_asignacion_materials
    FOR EACH ROW 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE det_ingreso_materials SET cantidad = cantidad - NEW.cantidad
            WHERE det_ingreso_materials.material_id = NEW.material_id;
        END
;;
```

Aunque la sintaxis que tenías al inicio de tu pregunta también era válida (*con las correcciones mencionadas*)

```
DELIMITER//
    CREATE TRIGGER reducirCantidad AFTER INSERT ON det_asignacion_materials
    FOR EACH ROW 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE det_ingreso_materials SET cantidad = cantidad - NEW.cantidad
            WHERE det_ingreso_materials.material_id = NEW.material_id;
        END
//
```

**Referencias**

- [Sintaxis de triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: Gracias @BetaM, me faltaba el ; y el ON